# Is it possible to visit the Bundaberg Rum Distillery in a day trip from Brisbane, without a car?

Tags: public-transport, alcohol, day-trips, brisbane, queensland

Since coming to Queensland, I've tried Bundaberg rum, cooked with Bundaberg sugar, and now I've found out about the possibility to [visit the Bundaberg Rum Distillery](http://www.bundabergrum.com.au/Our-Home). Several people have recommended the distillery tour to me, saying it's very interesting and well done, plus it has a tasting at the end!

The only thing is I don't currently have a car with me. Is it possible to get to Bundaberg to do the tour in a day trip from Brisbane by public transport? Or does it require at least one night away? (Borrowing / Hiring a car might be an option, but sounds less fun as you wouldn't really be able to take part in the tasting, and it's a fair drive for a single day)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Difficult.  You're probably going to want to spend a night.  In which case you could take a car.

IF you wanted to take the train, the service is the [Queensland Rail Tilt Train](http://www.queenslandrail.com.au/RailServices/Travelnetwork/Pages/TiltTrain.aspx).

However, the [earliest departure north is 11.55am](http://www.queenslandrail.com.au/RailServices/Travelnetwork/Pages/RockhamptonTiltTrainNorthboundTimetable.aspx), and you won't reach Bundaberg until 3.30pm.

Coming back, depending on the day, you [could be back in the morning if you get the earliest departure](http://www.queenslandrail.com.au/RailServices/Travelnetwork/Pages/RockhamptonTiltTrainSouthboundTimetable.aspx).

---

Then you've got the [Brisbane to Cairns Tilt Train](http://www.queenslandrail.com.au/RailServices/Travelnetwork/Pages/CairnsTiltTrainNorthboundTimetable.aspx), but there the departure times out of Brisbane are in the evening, so even less useful.

---

Finally, you have the [Sunlander](http://www.queenslandrail.com.au/RailServices/Travelnetwork/Pages/TheSunlanderNorthboundTimetable.aspx.), which is meant to be one of the top rail journeys in the world.  However, for getting to Bundaberg, your departure time in Brisbane is 9am, getting you in at 4pm, and returning times are 9.15am.  They only run some days of the week (it's a long line).

---

Bus is going to be similar, unless you fancy some wee hour coach journey, if you can find it.  Even in 2004 when I was doing a scenic flight out of Hervey Bay (next to Bundaberg) we got up early in Mooloolaba, rather than try and get there from Brisbane.

---

Final option - Bundaberg does have an airport, there may be a convenient flight from Brisbane, and you could get a bus/train back, or vice-versa?